# Options to use Java free for commercial use

Tags: java

If I want to keep my software (be it an application or even a game for Windows) free for me as developer/publisher as well as my users/clients what should I do (use)/can I even do that today?

To download the JDK you have two options (that I know of): [OpenJDK](https://openjdk.org) / [jdk.java.net](https://jdk.java.net/18/) and [Oracle JDK](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk18-windows). Am I right to assume that you can use everything from **OpenJDK** free of charge for commercial use as well, while **Oracle JDK** depends how they stand, some are free while for some you need a subscription ([JDK 17/18 says](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk-faqs.html) that they are free under NFTC while for JDK 8 you need a subscription)?

As for JRE, can I download Java from [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp) (version: Windows Offline (64-bit)) and add it in a folder with the software, to check if the user/client has it or not, and prompt an install it they don't have it?

Comment: see [Why isn't it required to provide comments/feedback for downvotes, and why are proposals suggesting this so negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/16320675)  - this *topic* - I do not mean that specific Question -  is very *old* on StackOverflow...

Answer (score 2):

> To download the JDK you have two options (that I know of)

Oh, heck no. There's *Temurin* by Adoptium, *Zulu* by Azul Systems, *Coretto* by Amazon. Other vendors include Red Hat, IBM, SAP, BellSoft, Microsoft, Oracle, Pivotal, etc.

> Am I right to assume that you can use everything from OpenJDK free of charge for commercial use as well

Yes. But note that they stop supporting it when a new version comes out. I'd use Adoptium or Coretto instead.

Comment: By "they stop supporting it" do you mean that when a new version comes out they are still free but don't get any more new updates (for features/security)?

Comment: @sValentin OpenJDK is formally a "source-only" project, where the various vendors that participate in the project (Oracle, Microsoft, Eclipse Adoptium, Azul, etc) are responsible for releasing actual binaries and providing support.